# filtering a list by value and list of indexes

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def find_value_indexes(item_list, index_list, v):
    """ (list of object, list of int, object) -> list of int

    Precondition: the values in index_list are valid indexes in item_list.

    v may appear multiple times in item_list.  index_list contains zero or
    more indexes.  
    Return a list of the indexes from index_list at which v
    appears in item_list.

    >>> find_value_indexes([6, 8, 8, 5, 8], [0, 2, 4], 8)
    [2, 4]
    """

    result = []
    for i in range(len(item_list)):
        for j in range(len(index_list)):
            if item_list[i] == v:
                result.append(index_list[j])
    return result
```

My function wouldn't work because it returns more than what I am supposed to get. What can I do?

Comment: Think about what happens if length of `index_list` is smaller than `item_list` i.e `i > j`. What would `index_list[i]` print when the value of i is more than j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate `item_list` - just to iterate `index_list` and use its elements as indexes for `item_list`:

```
result = []
for i in index_list:
    if item_list[i] == v:
         result.append(i)
return result
```

Or, more elegantly, in as a one-liner using list comprehensions:

```
return [i for i in index_list if item_list[i] == v]
```